# Token For pushnotification ios8 vs ios7 phonegap

Tags: objective-c

Im using the following code lines for getting token for push notification,

i added the next lines for supported in ios8, but when these lines are added the ipa works on ios8 but not on ios7 on ios7 the application is closed immediately after i open it.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{

#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
    //Right, that is the point
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge
                                                                                         |UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound
                                                                                         |UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
#else
    //register to receive notifications
    UIRemoteNotificationType myTypes = UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:myTypes];
#endif

#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
    //register to receive notifications
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler
{
    //handle the actions
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"declineAction"]){
    }
    else if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"answerAction"]){
    }
}
#endif
```

Comment: What is the exception you see when running the app on iOS 7?

Comment: registerUserNotificationSettings:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16d71c60
2014-10-31 12:56:00.899 ClickMobileCDV[1875:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIApplication registerUserNotificationSettings:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16d71c60'
*** First throw call stack:

Answer (score 10):

Since iO8, `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes` has been deprecated . `rgisterUserNotificationSettings:` with registerForRemoteNotifications.

Testing wether or not the `registerUserNotificationSettings`: API is available at runtime, means you're running on iOS8.

```
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
        UIUserNotificationSettings* notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    } else {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

The solution:

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
    if(NSFoundationVersionNumber > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1) {
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound|UIUserNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    }
#else
    //register to receive notifications
    UIRemoteNotificationType myTypes = UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:myTypes];
#endif
```

Comment: the #ifdef is a pre-processor directive.  Can you ship a binary with that to the App Store and it will work for both iOS7 and iOS8?